PC doesn't wake after sleep
I'm trying to have my PC sleep at a certain time (00:05) and wake up at 07:00.
            SYSTEMTIME sT;
            GetLocalTime(&sT);
            if (sT.wHour == 0)
            {
                if (sT.wMinute >= 5)
                {
                    SYSTEMTIME sT = {};
                    GetLocalTime(&sT);
                    sT.wHour = 5; // UTC+2 I am
                    sT.wMinute = 0;
                    sT.wSecond = 0;
                    sT.wMilliseconds = 0;                       
                    LARGE_INTEGER WaitTime = {};
                    SystemTimeToFileTime(&sT, (LPFILETIME)&WaitTime);
                    HANDLE hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
                    if (hTimer)
                    {
                        if (SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &WaitTime, 0, NULL, NULL, TRUE))
                        {
                            if (SetSuspendState(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))
                            {
                            }
                        }
                        CloseHandle(hTimer);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Before that I 've enabled the shutdown token:
        SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITIES sysPowCab = { 0 };
        if (CallNtPowerInformation(SystemPowerCapabilities, NULL, 0, &sysPowCab, sizeof(SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITIES)) == 0)
        {
            HANDLE hToken = 0;
            TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp = {};

            if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),
                TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
            {
            LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME,
                &tkp.Privileges[0].Luid);

            tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;  // one privilege to set    
            tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

            // Get the shutdown privilege for this process. 
            AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0,
                (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, 0);

                    //Enable allow wake up timer
                    GUID* pPwrGUID;
                    GUID subGUID = GUID_SLEEP_SUBGROUP;
                    GUID BriGUID = GUID_ALLOW_RTC_WAKE;

                    DWORD ret = PowerGetActiveScheme(NULL, &pPwrGUID);
                    if (ret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
                    {
                        ret = PowerWriteACValueIndex(NULL, pPwrGUID, &subGUID, &BriGUID, 1);
                        if (ret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
        }

This only works if I set it to very close time, like 5 minutes after sleep. Otherwise it doesn't work.
What could be the issue? Power Options -> Wake Timers = enabled already.

Your indentation suggests that part of the shown code is missing, or inconsistently structured or indented. Please double check.
